# Dependency injection model within asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am currently developing a .NET MVC 5 site, and I have a question about increasing quality. I've picked up the project from another developer and there is quite a bit of code smell throughout the project so I'm trying to clean up the project. The issue I'm having is a high amount of class coupling and consequently low cohesion. (In defense of the developer, his front end JS code is fantastic and gets very solid scores from static analysis tools). The current issue I'm having has to do with class coupling of helpers in the project. This is the current implementation:

```
...
Type iaccounthelpertype = typeof(IAccountsHelper), igettabletype = typeof(IGettable);
List<Tuple<IAccountsHelper, IGettable>> valid = new List<Tuple<IAccountsHelper, IGettable>>();
// Get all the types that implement IAccountsHelper and IGettable
IEnumerable<Type> types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => iaccounthelpertype.IsAssignableFrom(p) && igettabletype.IsAssignableFrom(p))
    .Select(x => x);

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Get");
    try
    {
        methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        IAccountsHelper helper = methodInfo.Invoke(null, null) as IAccountsHelper;
        valid.Add(Tuple.Create<IAccountsHelper, IGettable>(helper, helper as IGettable));
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException nullref)
    {
        // this is bad. The new object does not implement the proper static method. So we will carry this exception through.
        throw new Exception(type.Name + " does not implement the static generic method Get");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
...
```

This code allows for the following implementation (the function name above is called Get)

```
IAccountsHelper helper = TheParentClass<UserPrincipal>.Get();
```

So now any code using the "helper" object can expect any operations performed by the class to be of type UserPrincipal (So like an ActiveDirectory helper that would create users). So far this has had a nicer implementation for any unit of code needing a helper without having a higher coupling rate, increasing cohesion. It just calls this class, tells it what type of object it should be operating with, and this function will map it to the appropriate class. I did all of this because I couldn't figure out a way too handle dependency injection within an MVC / web api project. But I feel like this code is dirty, and I think their maybe a better way to achieve what I am doing. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could, or if this code isn't dirty, etc?

As a note, I'm using the visual studio code metrics window to get the class coupling of the project, which decreased from 436 to 401,  with 5,909 lines of code. (I find you need the two to have a nice estimation of cohesion).

Comment: Why couldn't you figure out a way to handle dependency injection? Have you tried using Nuget to grab Ninject MVC?

Comment: Well this was kind of my attempt at trying to handle it. No, I haven't even heard of that, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC actually has excellent support for dependency injection frameworks. One of the most popular is Ninject. If you use the NuGet Package Manager to bring the [Ninject MVC 5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/) package into your web project, it'll do much of the setup magic itself. Then you just need to add a binding in its setup area:

```
Bind<IAccountsHelper>().To<UserPrincipal>();
```

And then use constructor injection in any classes that require one of these:

```
public MyController(IAccountsHelper accountsHelper)
{
    _accountsHelper = accountsHelper;
}
```